# Why would I want to find the rate at which things were changing? Marginal cost, marginal revenue and profit

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm learning calc and after learning about how to differentiate using product rule and chain rule etc. I came across marginal cost and marginal revenue. I'm pretty familiar with cost, profit and revenue. Why would I want to find the marginal revenue (aka rate of change for revenue or cost)? What does this rate of change give me? Without getting too mechanical and mathematical, can someone explain why I want to know the so called rate of change?

Answer (score 1):

Great question and there are many potential answers to this question. Let me give you one that from my experience is used extensively.

Suppose you have a firm that produces widgets. A widget sells for \$300, and it costs \$100 per unit, if you only produce 5; the next 5 will cost \$200 per unit to produce, the next 5 \$300, etc.

How much would the firm choose to produce? If you look at total costs, you might reason that it pays the firm to produce up to 17 units, for it will cost 5*100+5*200+5*300+3*400=4200 and it will sell for 17*300=5100, hence a profit of 5100-4200=900. Not bad, right?

Well, let us now look at marginal cost. The marginal cost of producing the 15th unit is 300, but the cost of producing the 16th is 400. Just looking at the margin, it is clear that it will not pay to produce more than 15 units. To verify, if the firm produces 15 units, it will cost 5*100+5*200+5*300=3000 and it will sell for 15*300=4500. A profit of \$1500! much better than \$900!

That should, I hope, give you some basic intuition as to why thinking in marginal costs is more useful than thinking in terms of total profit.

Comment: The dollar signs are messing up your formatting.  We use dollar signs as an escape character for $\LaTeX$, so to just get a dollar sign you need dollar backslash dollar dollar to get $\$$

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in the case of maximizing profit. Let profit be represented by $\pi$. we see $\pi$ is generally a function of our cost(C) and revenue (R) since our profit is just revenue minus cost. Letting $x$ be the goods we are selling we see revenue and cost are a function of $x$ (i.e. $R(x)$ and $C(x)$).Thus 
$$\pi(C(x),R(x))=R(x)-C(x)$$
Well to find amount we should sell to maximize profit we just use calculus to find critical point 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\pi(C(x),R(x))=\frac{d}{dx}\left(R(x)-C(x)\right)=\frac{dR}{dx}-\frac{dC}{dx}=0$$
Thus maximum point will be at (of course also have check is maximum with second derivative but I leave you to see that)
$$\frac{dR}{dx}=\frac{dC}{dx}$$
Well $\dfrac{dR}{dx}$ is just marginal revenue (MR) and $\dfrac{dC}{dx}$ is just marginal Cost (MC) so we maximize profit when MC=MR. Which should make sense since as long as when we increase x marginally if revenue generated is greater than cost acquired then we will keep increasing x we do this until the marginal revenue earned is equal to marginal cost (because after words the cost acquired will be greater than revenue thus resulting in negative profit)

This is just a glimpse why we want to look at marginal revenue. It basically comes down to that much economic and finical thinking deals with efficiency and optimization. Where these problem can be solved using calculus (thinking at the margin)

Comment: If that is to math of an explanation I can try to explain it another way

Comment: Yea thats way too mechanical for my understanding. How would you explain the importance of rate of change to an algebra 2 student?